# when installing a R package, fatal error: R.h: No such file or directory, How to locate R.h?

Tags: r, g++, r-package

when installing a R package from github

```
install_github("DataSlingers/ExclusiveLasso")
```

I get the error messages:

```
* installing *source* package 'ExclusiveLasso' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'D:/R-4.2.2/library/Rcpp/include' -I'D:/R-4.2.2/library/RcppArmadillo/include'   -I"D:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c ExclusiveLasso.cpp -o ExclusiveLasso.o
In file included from D:/R-4.2.2/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:30,
                 from D:/R-4.2.2/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo/interface/RcppArmadilloForward.h:25,
                 from D:/R-4.2.2/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:29,
                 from ExclusiveLasso.cpp:23:
D:/R-4.2.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:66:10: fatal error: R.h: No such file or directory
   66 | #include <R.h>
      |          ^~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [D:/R-4.2.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:260：ExclusiveLasso.o] 错误 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'ExclusiveLasso'
* removing 'D:/R-4.2.2/library/ExclusiveLasso'
```

I know where my R.h at, and I tried change

```
#include <R.h>
```

into

```
#include <D:/R-4.2.2/include>,
```

but there's too many files and errors like this

It seems that I should tell the g++ where to find D:/R-4.2.2/include, can someone guide me whether I should do that or what should I do.

I's using:
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Using vscode

Comment: It looks likes this is an open issue on the GitHub page for this package: https://github.com/DataSlingers/ExclusiveLasso/issues/18

Comment: that's me too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine here on Ubuntu 22.10.  Note in the log below how it uses `-I"/usr/share/R/include"` (which is something R itself adds) to point to R's headers.  So to me it looks like your R installation is at fault because the [src/Makevars.win](https://github.com/DataSlingers/ExclusiveLasso/blob/master/src/Makevars.win) in that repo is very standard and mostly likely correct.

```
edd@rob:~$ installGithub.r DataSlingers/ExclusiveLasso  # wrapper around install_github()
Using github PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT
Downloading GitHub repo DataSlingers/ExclusiveLasso@HEAD

Skipping 1 packages ahead of CRAN: Rcpp
── R CMD build ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file ‘/tmp/remotes2ac86f2646632b/DataSlingers-ExclusiveLasso-ed6b729/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘ExclusiveLasso’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘ExclusiveLasso_0.0.tar.gz’
   
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘ExclusiveLasso’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
ccache g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include'    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wno-ignored-attributes  -c ExclusiveLasso.cpp -o ExclusiveLasso.o
ccache g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include'    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wno-ignored-attributes  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
ccache g++ -std=gnu++11 -Wl,-S -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -o ExclusiveLasso.so ExclusiveLasso.o RcppExports.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
if test -e "/usr/bin/strip" & test -e "/bin/uname" & [[ `uname` == "Linux" ]] ; then /usr/bin/strip --strip-debug *.o *.so; fi
if test -e "/usr/bin/strip" & test -e "/bin/uname" & [[ `uname` == "Darwin" ]] ; then /usr/bin/strip -S *.o *.so; fi
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-ExclusiveLasso/00new/ExclusiveLasso/libs
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (ExclusiveLasso)
edd@rob:~$
```

Looking at your installation attempt confirms that because you have

```
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"/include"
```

so R does not figure out where its installation is.  Normally you should have

```
edd@rob:~$ R RHOME
/usr/lib/R
edd@rob:~$
```

but I suspect that too is borked at your end.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved~ I had tried reinstall my R and same error, then I figure it might be the Rcpp's problem, after I re-install the Rcpp package, the error gone

Comment: Well glad you have it working but you have the wrong mental model here as it cannot have anything to do with Rcpp as Rcpp has exactly zero influence over where R finds its own headers.